# How to create a custom search box without using indexer(lucene) and google custom search

Tags: java, jsp

I need to create a custom search box for my site which contains dynamic pages, when i enter details in search box and click on search it should search entire website and return results present in that particular website.

But i need an approach other than google custom search and indexer such as lucene.

I am also looking for any third party vendors who provide free indexing.

Comment: Without an index? Good luck!

Comment: hi qqilihq, thanks for reply i am ready to use indexing but not lucene or solr. Any third party which provides free indexing? Any idea?